# In java, why I can declare a variable named "a" but not "1" ?

Tags: java, variables, declaration

Everything is fine when I declare

```
String a;
```

but it says **Syntax error on token "1", invalid VariableDeclaratorId** when I do this

```
String 1;
```

Why is that?

Comment: Or better yet: use a name that describes the variables function rather than its value.

Comment: Are you from the Forth planet?

Comment: I have always found it annoying to have to use those pesky quotes around string literals. I think Mr Gupta is pulling someone's leg.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, first of all, it's because it's written in the Java language Specification.

But, maybe that this example will help you more:

```
String 1 = "toto"
System.out.println(1 + 2)
```

What should be the output?

Comment: Expanding this thought: *replacing* the function/value of an object is **rarely** a good idea. You make it harder to maintain your own code: imagine if there were 500 lines between gizmo's two lines. Would you be able to troubleshoot why you couldn't add two numbers?
 
That being said, *extending* the function of an object can make sense in the correct context.

Comment: In FORTRAN, one could use floating-point literals as variables, sort of, though writing to them was a pain and I don't think there was any guarantee as to whether multiple uses of the same floating-point number would represent the same variable or not.

Answer (score 7):

Because `1` is also a value (which, among others, you can assign) the parser cannot know what you mean.

Consider the following snippet:

```
int 1 = 10;
int a = 1; // what is the value of a ? 1 or 10?
```

Therefore, starting a variable name with a number is dissallowed. You can use `_1` instead if you really want (note that it is difficult to read though)

Comment: Suffixes to variables make a distinction between different value types. For examples 1L means that this is a value of the type Long, not integer. Or 0x... means that there is a hex-value following.

Answer (score 4):

The rules for [identifiers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.8) in the Java language specification state that you cannot start an identifier with a number.

Answer (score 3):

The parser can't distinguish it from the int literal, so it's disallowed.

Comment: Why char and int literal treated so differently ?

Comment: Char literals have quotes around them.

Comment: Because one of them is a name of a variable, the other one is a value. If you couldn't distinguish them by their naming conventions, how else should the compiler find out if it's dealing with a variable name or a value?

Answer (score 2):

Not only the parser would have a great deal of effort distinguishing between an `int` literal and a variable (if not totally impossible) but you could end up with strange situations like:

```
int 1 = 999;
System.out.println(1);

// output: 1 or 999
```

Basically this doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can.
It compiles on my machine.

Comment: Yes, it does. 
here is the code: 

public static void main(String args[]) 
{
   String 1 = "one"; 
}

it does compile on jdk1.1.3

Comment: jdk1.1.3? Heh! Thats several decades ago! :-D

Comment: Hi Dolphenstein, 
Not everybody can use the latest jdk. Huh ?

Comment: nice to know that it was possible before Java 2 :)

Comment: That's not true. This was never allowed in Java and also the 1.1.3 compiler would reject this. Altough you could always have a variable named "1" in the class file (still in the lastest Java 1.6), but not in the source.

Answer (score 0):

Because `1` is a value. What will someone make of this :

```
String 1 = "6";
String s = 1 + "00";    // With value "100" or "600"?
```

Similarly, `true`, `false`, `null` cannot be variable names.

Answer (score 0):

It works on my machine too:
public static void main(String args[])
{ String l = "one"; } 
I am on jdk1.7

Comment: Yes, the lowercase letter "L" is a valid identifier in Java, as your compiler says. But the question wasn't about that. It was about the digit "1", which is not a valid identifier. Try it...